# Assert that method has been called using xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a class with a logging method that I want to test. For the example I want to check if the `Console.WriteLine` method has been called. This is my sample class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void LogSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
```

and its test

```
public class MyClassTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void LogsSomething()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            
        myClass.LogSomething(); // Assert that Console.WriteLine has been called once
    }
}
```

Is there something I can use? (Preferably without additional packages)

I am looking for assertions like this (Pseudo code)

- `Assert.Method(Console.WriteLine).ToHaveBeenCalledWith(myClass.LogSomething);`
- `Assert.Method(Console.WriteLine).ToHaveBeenCalledWith(myClass.LogSomething).Times(3); // Check if Console.WriteLine has been called 3 times (loop inside the LogSomething method)`

Comment: Hmm you should use mocking package... You cannot call Console.WriteLine directly. Create some interface for logging. Then use mocking library to create fake instance of logger. Of course you can redirect console out to your custom TextWriter but it is pointless.

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://www.jondjones.com/architecture/unit-testing/mocking/how-to-use-moq-to-ensure-a-method-was-called-or-not-called/ - I think you will have to use some Dependency Injection and Mocking (Moq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you cannot assert that out of the box.

Your best bet is using `Moq` or another mock framework to do something along this lines.
You should always aim for a decoupled logic using dependency injection, otherwise you will end up having a tightly coupled code that is difficult to test and will not be easy to refactor whenever a change in requirements arrives

```
public interface ILogger
{
    public void Log();    
}
```

```
public class Logger: ILogger
{
    public void Log()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Look mom, i'm logging");
    }
}
```

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger Logger
    
    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //other code
        Logger.Log();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyClassTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void LogsSomething()
    {
      //arrange
      var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();   
      
      //act
      var sut = new MyClass(logger.Object);
      sut.MyMethod();

      //Assert 
      logger.Verify(foo => foo.Log(), Times.Once()); //here
      //some other assertions
    }
}
```